# cannot modify specific element in array of objects

Tags: arrays, lisp, common-lisp

```
(defclass schedule ()
   ((day :accessor schedule-day :initarg :day)))
(setf october 
   (make-array '(31) 
      :element-type 'schedule 
      :initial-element 
         (make-instance 'schedule :day 0)))
(setq searcher (read))
(setf (schedule-day (aref october (- searcher 1))) searcher)

(dotimes (i 31)
  (format t "-month:10 day:~S~%" (schedule-day (aref october i))))
```

This is part of my october scheduling program. 
This part should get the day I typed and change that day's day element, and print every october schedule.

however,

```
(setq searcher (read))
(setf (schedule-day (aref october (- searcher 1))) searcher)
```

I have trouble in this. if I type 17, then only 17th day of `october` should affected and printed like this,

```
-month:10 day:0
-month:10 day:0
...
-month:10 day:17
-month:10 day:0    
...
```

but what I really got is

```
-month:10 day:17
-month:10 day:17
-month:10 day:17
...
```

why I can't change only one element? I managed to do this in c++ like,

```
october[searcher - 1].setDay(searcher);
```

It seems `setf` affects the class itself, not class object. can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Please fix parens and indentation. Your code is now unreadable.

Comment: I assume it is ok now? it's just a class and a make-array :p

Comment: If initial-element is supplied, it is used to initialize each element of new-array (with the same object you pass)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that your array contains 31 pointers, each pointing to the same object.

Thus `(setf (schedule-day (aref october a)) b)` modifies that unique object.

You can achieve what you want by either encapsulating `october` so that the `i`th element is created only as necessary, or by initializing the array with something like

```
(apply #'vector (loop repeat 31 collect (make-instance 'schedule)))
```

or

```
(make-array 31 :initial-contents (loop repeat 31 collect (make-instance 'schedule)))
```

The root cause of your confusion is that you specified the array element-type and assumed that you created a ["specialized" array](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/15_ab.htm).
Thus, despite the fact that you actually call `(make-instance 'schedule)` just once, you will have 31 objects in contiguous memory.
However, your implementation is *not* obligated to honor the
element-type specification in *that* way (it will create an array which
can hold the objects of the type you specified, but not necessarily
*only* those objects), 
and what you actually got is a [`simple-vector`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_smp_ve.htm).

PS. You should
use [`defvar` or `defparameter`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm)
instead of [`setq`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_setq.htm)
or [`setf`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_setf_.htm) to define global
variables (like `october`), and you should name them
using
["earmuffs"](https://google.github.io/styleguide/lispguide.xml#Global_variables_and_constants),
like `*october*`.

Comment: sorry, I think I almost got it but consider me as a serious noob; how do I access that vector made by your code? I tried (setf october (vector blah blah)) and I think I'm doing it wrong...

Comment: Thank you very much! you're a life saver! oh, and at :initial-content you mean :initial-contents?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily see that the array elements are pointing to just one CLOS object.

```
CL-USER 28 > (defclass foo () ())
#<STANDARD-CLASS FOO 4020002613>

CL-USER 29 > (make-array 3 :initial-element (make-instance 'foo))
#(#<FOO 402000AE9B> #<FOO 402000AE9B> #<FOO 402000AE9B>)
```

All objects have the same ID `402000AE9B`.

In the next example the objects are different:

```
CL-USER 30 > (make-array 3 :initial-contents (list (make-instance 'foo)
                                                   (make-instance 'foo)
                                                   (make-instance 'foo)))
#(#<FOO 4020000B43> #<FOO 4020000B63> #<FOO 4020000B83>)
```

All have different IDs.